# how to avoid a function in javascript to get called with new keyword

Tags: javascript

Any function in JavaScript can be called using `new` keyword, is there any way to create a function which cannot be called with `new` keyword.

**EDIT**

I am just curious, if it is possible to do it? Since I try to execute `new alert()`, where alert looks like a function to me, i got an error. I am dont know why it happened with alert and if there is any way  to achieve same with normal functions in JavaScript.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to restrict your functions getting used with new keyword. What are you trying to achieve actually. There are alternatives of creating objects other than using with new keyword, can state in detail if u r looking for that...

Comment: @vishwanath it is possible.

Comment: Added explanation, why i want to do it.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya Can you please add it as a answer then? Will be helpful for us...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you could perform a test on `this`:

```
function test() {
    if (this instanceof test) {
        throw new Error('yikes');
    }
}

new test(); // yikes!
test();
```

Comment: +1, in the particular case of the alert method, it seems however to throw an error whenever it detects that `this` is not the global object.

Comment: @basilikum I suppose internal functions have a discrete advantage here :)

Answer (score 1):

No, `new` is one of the key features of JS, you can only change a behavior of your function to act the same with new and without new using `bind()`:

```
function_to_call = function_to_call.bind(your_object);
```

`function_to_call` will always have `your_object` as context.

Comment: This won't work in IE <= 8 unless we define our own bind function on function's prototype.

Answer (score 1):

There is a work-around for that.

```
function Foo() {
    if (this instanceof Foo) {
        //Calling with new keyword
        console.log("Calling with new keyword");
    } else {
        //calling without new keyword
        console.log("Calling without new keyword");
    }
}
```

The idea is to check if we’re currently inside the function itself and not in an instantiated version of the function.

[Read more](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/) at John Resig's blog.

Comment: Thanks, solves my problem.

Comment: Adding your own protection, that's smart cheating... Anyway most of the smart features like function overloading, private properties are smart cheating only. This is why I love javascript. Always proving me wrong when I think it cant do something :)